# Looping through list comma separated parameter and fetch results based on the every value before comma

Tags: sql, for-loop, plsql, while-loop, plsqldeveloper

The input parms are 2 ids(from_id and to_id) that are comma separated. Each id must be evaluated as the report is run . From_id='202031,202032,202035,202041,...'
To_id ='202111,202112,202135,202141,...'
Should filter the records for each from _id and while printing to log file the corresponding to_id should be printed. Always be 202031 to 202111, 202032 to 202112, 202035 to 202135, 20241 to 202141 . Below is the expected result.

```
Num_ber Description person_id   person_name Rolled_To_term  From_id to_id   term_priority_to_term   max_amt_to_term
    90010001    fund1   1           abc          N           202031 202111     3                     23  
    90010001    fund1   1           abc          N           202032 202112     6                     110
    50010001    fund2   2           xyz          N           202035 202135     2                     45 
    50010001    fund2   3           efg          N           202035 202135     5                     50
```

Below procedure updates the to_id ,but the from_id remains 202031 and gets looped again . The cursor does not filter for the other frm_id's.

```
PROCEDURE report_v1 (
    p_frm_id_list  VARCHAR2,
    p_to_id_list    VARCHAR2
) AS
exemp_log_file      utl_file.file_type;
log_msg             VARCHAR2(600);
frm_id_list       VARCHAR2(50);
frm_id_list_temp  VARCHAR2(50);
frm_id             VARCHAR2(50);
to_id_list         VARCHAR2(50);
to_id_list _temp   VARCHAR2(50);
to_id             VARCHAR2(50);   



CURSOR get_expt_info_c IS
SELECT
    code                 AS num_ber,
    desc                 AS description,
    a.term_expiration    AS exp_term,
    (select p_id from tab3 c where a.id=c.id) as person_id,
    (select p_name from tab3 c where a.id=c.id) as person_name,
    a.term_code          AS from_id,
    nvl(
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                'Y'
            FROM
                tab2 b
            WHERE
                    b.term_code = to_term
                AND b.id = a.id
        ), 'N'
    ) rolled_to_term,
    a.priority           AS term_priority_to_term,
    a.amount             AS max_amt_to_term
    
FROM
         tab left
    JOIN tab2 a ON code = a.code
                   AND term_code = a.term_code
WHERE
    instr(
        frm_id, a.term_code
    ) > 0;

BEGIN
    exemp_log_file := utl_file.fopen(dir,'report.csv','w');
    log_msg := 'Report header';
    utl_file.put_line(exemp_log_file,log_msg,autoflush => true );
    frm_id_list := replace(p_frm_id_list ,' ','');
    to_id_list := replace( p_ to_id_list, ' ','' );

WHILE frm_id_list IS NOT NULL LOOP
    IF instr( frm_id_list,',') > 0 THEN
        frm_id := substr(frm_id_list,1,instr(frm_id_list,',') - 1 );

        frm_id_list_temp := substr(frm_id_list,instr(frm_id_list,',' ) + 1);
    ELSE
        frm_id := frm_id_list;
        frm_id_list_temp := NULL;
    END IF;

    frm_id_list := frm_id_list_temp;
    


 WHILE to_id_list IS NOT NULL LOOP
       IF instr(to_id_list,',' ) > 0 THEN
           to_id := substr(to_id_list,1,instr(to_id_list,',' ) - 1 );

                to_id_list_temp := substr(to_id_list,instr(to_id_list,',' ) + 1 );
       ELSE
           to_id := to_id_list;
           to_id_list_temp := NULL;
       END IF;

       to_id_list := to_id_list_temp;
   FOR exemp IN get_expt_info_c LOOP
            utl_file.put_line(
                exemp_log_file,
                exemp.num_ber
                || ';'
                || exemp.description
                || ';'
                || exemp.exp_term
                || ';'
                || exemp.person_id
                || ';'
                || exemp.person_name
                || ';'
                || exemp.from_id
                || ';'
                || exemp.rolled_to_term
                || ';'
                || exemp.priority
                || ';'
                || exemp.amt
                || ';'
                || to_id,
                              autoflush => true
            );
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN no_data_found THEN
       NULL;
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
       EXIT;
        utl_file.fclose(exemp_log_file);
END report_v1;
```

TABLE DEFINITION &Sample DATA

```
CREATE TABLE "TAB" 
   (CODE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "TERM_CODE" VARCHAR2(6 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DESC" VARCHAR2(30 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DETAIL_CODE" VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ACTIVITY_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
)   

CODE      TERM_CODE   DESC    DETAIL_CODE   ACTIVITY_DATE
90010001  202031      fund1   aaa           09-Jun-2009    

CREATE TABLE."TAB2" 
   ("CODE" VARCHAR2(8 CHAR), 
    "ID" NUMBER(8,0), 
    "TERM_CODE" VARCHAR2(6 CHAR), 
    "ACTIVITY_DATE" DATE,    
    "TERM_EXPIRATION" VARCHAR2(6 CHAR),  
    "PRIORITY" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "AMOUNT" NUMBER(7,2) 
    )
    
CODE      ID    TERM_CODE   ACTIVITY_DATE   TERM_EXPIRATION     PRIORITY   AMOUNT
90010001  1     202031      09-Jun-2009     31-DEC-2030          3          23


CREATE TABLE "TAB3" 
   ("P_ID" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,     
    "P_NAME" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ACTIVITY_DATE" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE
    )
    
P_ID  P_NAME    ACTIVITY_DATE
1     abc       01-JAN-2007
```

Can anybody suggest a better way /alternative to my approach or correct my procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Your description indicated you are splitting 2 CSV strings into their individual elements them combining the split elements into a set of 2 elements, one from each string. This can be accomplished in a single sql statement:

```
with parms( from_ids, to_ids) as 
     ( select '202031,202032,202035,202041'  
            , '202111,202112,202135,202141' 
         from dual 
     )
select from_id, to_id
  from ( select regexp_substr (from_ids, '[^,]+', 1, rownum) from_id
              , regexp_substr (to_ids, '[^,]+', 1, rownum)   to_id
              , 1+length(from_ids)-length(replace(from_ids,',','')) cf 
              , 1+ length(to_ids)-length(replace(to_ids,',',''))     ct 
           from parms 
           connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (from_ids, '[^,]+')) + 1
       )
where cf=ct;
```

If the initial strings do not contain the same number of elements the query returns no rows.  
I am not sure what to do with your procedure as what you have posted is invalid and did not produce any results other than compile errors. It does not reference the parameter "from_id_list" but does use the variants "frm_id_list" (defined) and "p_from_id_list" (not defined). As for the parameter "to_id_list" it attempts to use it an an LVALUE in assignment. Since it is defined as an IN parameter this is not allowed. Further the procedure does not refer to any local variables except "log_msg" and "exempt_log_file". Looks like you posted a prior version by mistake. You may want to edit your question and post the correct version.  
I does appear however that the 2 WHILE loops a are attempting to do the split and combine process. The query above replaces both. But how does that fit into the cursor loop?

Comment: Thank you for catching the missed/incorrected variables. Have edited the same. The query should filter by from id and while printing to exempt_log_file the to_id should be populated as per the from id of the cursor  . If the from id is 202031 then to_id should be 202111 and so on.

Comment: Progress, but please include table definitions (ddl) and sample input data - as text, **no images**, and if different from above the expected output of that data.

Comment: No change in the expected out .

Comment: OK but what are the table definitions and input data? You still have not posted either other that a list of numbers. What data is SELECTED?

Comment: table definitions updated (hope this is what you asked). Input data is similar to the expected output.

Comment: @arsha: Your input data **is not similar** to your expected output. You have described 3 tables used as input to arrive at the output. What is the exact (column by column) values from each table, especially any columns values used in the query that are not actually in the output.

Comment: Excuse for the delay. Have edited my question to include sample data. Thanks in Advance for your help .

Answer (score 0):

So, I have a project I built a while back that is pretty much identical to this one on github: https://github.com/DevNambi/sql-server-regex

You may want to download that, get it installed (C# deterministic regex functions wont break SQL Server), and then use Matches to get a result set of your matches and their values. With would allow something like this..

```
SELECT S.RelevantColumns,   TRY_CONVERT(INT, Match) as ID
FROM SourceTable S
    CROSS APPLY dbo.RegexMatches(S.IDlist, '(\d),') x
    INNER JOIN dbo.SomeOtherTable OT
        ON  OT.ID = TRY_CONVERT(INT, x.Match)
```

I've done this a few times when a reporting layout was not conducive to iteration like your cursor above. Let me know if this helps. I'm unsure entirely what the purpose of the entire script is, but hopefully this provides some insight into how to achieve this?